# Solve recurrence relation using master theorem

Tags: recurrence-relations

Maybe anyone has idea how to solve this recurrence relation using master theorem?
$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+log_2n+10$$
So $$a=2, b=2,f(n)=log_2n+10$$
I think that I should use first case, because $$\log_2n+10<n^{log_22}$$
So I should proof that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log_2n+10}{n^{1-\epsilon}}=0$$
But no idea how to proof that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $\epsilon= \frac{1}{2}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log_2n+10}{n^{1-\epsilon}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log_2n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and use L'Hospital rule.